# Can taking high doses of iodine every day cause psychosis?

Tags: thyroid, psychologist-psychology, psychiatrist-psychiatry, antipsychotic

I know few people who take high doses of iodine everyday.
They take this medicine called Lugola: https://www.cefarm24.pl/plyn-lugola-40-g-coel-roztwor-wodny-jodu-produkt-farmakopealny.html

1 g of liquid contains:
active substances - iodine 10 mg, potassium iodide 20 mg.

The total amount of idoine per ml in this solution is:

10 mg + 20 mg * 0,78 (this ratio is taken from another source)  = 10 mg + 15,4 mg = 25,4 mg of iodine/ml

This is an aqueous solution, so 1 ml is 20 drops, and one drop is 0.05 ml.
They take this every morning 2 to 5 drops from a very long time like 1 year.
The dose is 0.1 ml to 0.25 ml everyday, which translates into total doses of iodine ranging from 2,54 mg to 6,35 mg per day.

I've observed changes in behaviour of these people from the time they have started taking this. They seems to be more aggressive now and are afraid of non real things. Can this be beacuse of the fact that they take these doses of iodine everyday?

There is no condition to be treated with iodide, they do this because they believe this will improve their overall health.

Comment: @Krzysztof Cichocki, knowing the health condition, which is the probable reason to take Lugol's solution, could help in discussion about symptoms, which could be due to the disease or the drug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Drugs.com](https://www.drugs.com/mmx/lugol-s-solution.html) mentions that prolonged use of Lugol's solution (potassium iodide + iodine) can cause *confusion,* caused by potassium.

In long-term treatment of Grave's disease (overactive thyroid), 10–400 mg iodide per day has been used ([PubMed, 2107](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5693970/)).

Various drug websites do not mention psychosis, aggressiveness, illusions or irritability as a side effect of potassium iodide.

Grave's disease symptoms include irritability and anxiety, among others ([Mayo Clinic](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/graves-disease/symptoms-causes/syc-20356240)).